# ¿Cómo descomprimir un archivo RAR o ZIP en PHP?

Tags: php, zip

Estoy intentando descomprimir un archivo RAR que tengo almacenado en el almacenamiento de Laravel.

Intenté con las bibliotecas de PHP como `ZipArchive` o `RarArchive`, pero la primera cuando la uso me arroja este error:

[image: Captura del error]

[image: Captura del código]

La clase `RarArchive` me arroja:

[image: Otra captura con otro error]

Comment: Si usas linux debes usar `pecl install rar` (se necesita el paquete `php-dev`) y cuando termine la compilación te aparecen unas pequeñas instrucciones para poner en marcha la extensión. Si usas Windows debes descargar la DLL desde http://pecl.php.net/package/rar y agregar una entrada `extension=php_rar.dll` en tu `php.ini`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explicación de los errores

El primer mensaje de error (usando `ZipArchive`) es debido a que tratas de trabajar con un archivo RAR desde una clase que trabaja con archivos ZIP. Probablemente si abrieses un archivo ZIP no saldría ese mensaje de error.

El segundo mensaje de error (usando `RarArchive`) es debido a que no tienes instalada la extensión adecuada que proporciona la funcionalidad de trabajar con archivos RAR.

### Instalando extensiones PECL

Las clases `ZipArchive` y `RarArchive` se proporcionan a través de [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/).

En Linux basta con usar (teniendo los paquetes `php-dev` y `libzip-dev` entre otros):

```
pecl install rar zip
```

Y posteriormente agregar a `php.ini` las siguientes líneas y posteriormente reiniciar el servidor Apache o FPM:

```
extension=rar.so
extension=zip.so
```

En Windows debes descargar las DLL apropiadas desde:

- http://pecl.php.net/package/rar
- http://pecl.php.net/package/zip

Y descomprimir/copiar las DLLs en el directorio de extensiones de instalación de PHP (en XAMPP es `C:\xampp\php\ext`).

Y agregar las siguientes líneas a tu `php.ini` y después reiniciar el servidor Apache:

```
extension=php_rar.dll
extension=php_zip.dll
```

### Capturar errores correctamente

Dado que [`ZipArchive::open()`](https://php.net/es/ziparchive.open) devuelve `true` en caso de haber abierto correctamente el archivo ZIP, deberíamos hacer una comprobación estricta:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$path_rar = storage_path('app/imprenta/'. $attachment->getFilename());
// devuelve "C:\.../Data_Normalizacion_202109_20210906_out.rar"

/* Comparamos exactitud con "true" */
if ($zip->open($path_rar) === true) {
    $zip->extractTo(storage_path('app/imprenta'));
    $zip->close();
    dd("archivo descomprimido!");
} else {
    dd("Ha ocurrido un error al descomprimir!");
}
```

En caso contrario, cualquier valor distinto de `0` se convertirá a `true`.

En tu código la llamada está devolviendo un valor [`ZipArchive::ER_NOZIP`](https://github.com/pierrejoye/php_zip/blob/0b183b68a71c83c1f634804cb8b4d0aed875b8fc/php8/php_zip.c#L3124), que puedes ver que es una [constante entera](https://github.com/pierrejoye/php_zip/blob/0b183b68a71c83c1f634804cb8b4d0aed875b8fc/php8/php_zip.c#L451) con [valor `19`](https://github.com/pierrejoye/php_zip/blob/master/REFLECTION#L130).